# Array of ArrayLists in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to make an array of ArrayLists of Strings in java because I need a list of words for every letter of alphabet. 
I'm doing in in this way:

```
ArrayList<String>[] letters = new ArrayList[32];
```

But I'm getting a **NullPointerException** when I try to add something to my list.

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    letter = (int)line.charAt(0) - 1040;
    if (letters[letter] == null) {
        letters[letter] = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    letters[letter].add(line);
}
```

I also tried to create it like that

```
ArrayList<String>[] leters = (ArrayList<String>[])new ArrayList[32];
```

But it didn't changed the situation. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? My guess would be the `if` statement because `leters` is null, and not the array. Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, why 25? There are 26 letters in the base alphabet. Many languages have more than that.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/yO81XQ). As you may also notice, letter Z is missing since you only have 25 letters.

Comment: @Andreas the line `leters[letter].add(word);` gives an exception. Thanks for advice. ` if ` statement gives false and I don't know how to check it correctly.

Comment: That's impossible with the code you showed.

Comment: @Andreas I edited the example

Comment: Still not possible to get NullPointerException at the line with the `add()` call, since the `if` statement preceding it makes that impossible.

Comment: So you're using the cyrillic alphabet, but only the first 25? `АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШ`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a hash map:

```
HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>> letters  = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Then you can add words by doing:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add(word);
letters.put("A", words);
```